# Python logging handlers configured at DEBUG level, but only ERROR is printed

Tags: python

I set up logging as follows

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.config.dictConfig({
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'standard': {
                'format': LOG_FORMAT,
                'datefmt': ISO_1806_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'standard',
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'stream':  'ext://sys.stdout'
            },
            'file': {
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'formatter': 'standard',
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'filename': os.path.basename(__file__) + '.log'
            }
        },
        'root': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file']
        },
    })
```

Per the title, ERROR is printed to the log file, but not DEBUG nor INFO when I issue logging commands such as `logging.info("some info")`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the dict overwritten somewhere?

Comment: No, if I use `''` instead of `root` then `INFO` lines are printed but this affects logging in some libraries, which I don't want. My workaround has been to create a `loggers` entry in the map and instantiate a specific logger that has the rule explicitly set for that logger. This works for me, but I still don't understand the behavior described in the OP.